# Update appstore and playstore apps to completely different apps

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio

Hi i want to ask about playstore and appstore apps updates.

So currently i have application X in appstore and playstore that build using native language, then i have new version of application X build using flutter, lets call it XV1.

These 2 application have different code and architecture.

My question is it possible to replace application X with application XV1?

Thanks

Comment: For Apple AppStore, it's no problem as long as you maintain the same bundle ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I've already done this kind of operation for legacy applications, as long as you keep the same bundle identifier for iOS and the same package name for Android, you will also need the same signature keys.

### iOS

You can check and change your bundle identifier by opening `Runner.xcworkspace` in your app’s `ios` folder with Xcode.

[image]

Or directly in your `Info.plist` inside `ios/Runner`:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.example.example</string>
```

### Android

You can change your package name in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.example"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

You can also (re)create a flutter project and precise your package and bundle name as a parameter of the command:

```sh
flutter create --org com.example.example
```